# How to call Spring download url from angular controller

Tags: angularjs, url

I have an application in spring boot. Where I have a link for download a csv file. I need to integrate this link in angular's controller to give the option to user.

So, when user clicks on Download button from UI this link gets called and download pop saved in local system. I have a controller for this "report".

This is my link to download:

```
MY_SERVER_IP:8080/System/report/download/{id}/{epochTime}/{epochTime2}
```

I have tried like below:

```
<a target="_blank" href=" MY_SERVER_IP:8080/System/report/download/2378/1486029600000/1486036680000">Link</a>
```

But in console it is taking the server IP where angular is deployed.

```
http://WHERE_ANGULAR_APP_IS_DEPLOYED:8080/ANGULAR_PROJECT_NAME/MY_SERVER_IP:8080/System/report/download/2378/1486029600000/1486036680000
```

Sorry for this silly issue, but being new in angular, I am no able to figure it out how this gonna work.

Comment: Does the `href` starts with 'http://'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code is working for me, I don't know why I posted this question.

In html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="downloadReport(from_time, to_time)">Download Me</button>
```

Angular controller:

```
    $scope.downloadReport = function (from_time, to_time) {
    AngularService.getReportNow($scope.id, $scope.from_time, $scope.to_time);
}
```

Angular service: Call to Spring server.

```
    this.getReportNow= function (id, fromTime, toTime){
                console.log("Clicked on right place.....");
                //servicePath  = http://MY_SERVER_IP:8080/
                $window.location.href = servicePath + 'System/report/download/' + id + '/' + fromTime + '/' + toTime;
            }
```